# Auto generate documentation for sub packages using Sphinx

Tags: package, python-sphinx

My project has several packages and submodules. All of them have docstrings, so I'd like to automatically generate recursive sphinx documentation for all the project.

I see there are autodoc and autosummary extensions, but I can't make them work and I can't find clear guides about this.

Any hint?

Comment: http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-apidoc.html to generate stub files, assuming your project's packages are Python packages.

Comment: Similar questions: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46341816/407651, https://stackoverflow.com/q/25549321/407651

Comment: Perhaps you can use this extension: https://pypi.org/project/sphinx-autopackagesummary/

Answer (score 0):

From version 3.1, if you're happy to use `sphinx.ext.autosummary` to display summary tables, you can use the new `:recursive:` option to automatically detect every module in your package, however deeply nested, and automatically generate documentation for every attribute, class, function and exception in that module.

See my answer here, with example code and results: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62613202/12014259